# Change the color of selected or selected but not active listview row when using uxtheme theough winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, themes, uxtheme

im on Win10 and want to change the colors used when drawing a ListView control using uxtheme API.

But when drawing a ListView ListItem (`LVP_LISTITEM`) background through DrawThemeBackgroundEx it always gets drawn in this explorer like light blue when selected (`LISS_SELECTED`) or some light grey when selected but not active (`LISS_SELECTEDNOTFOCUS`).

Is there a way to have the selection color altered to some other color than this blue and grey which seems to be hardcoded in the theme?

Comment: It is not clear for me what you are doing? You are using custom draw or owner draw? Show us a minimum of code how you use your code!

Comment: The color comes from the theme. There's no documented way to change themes (although it's obviously possible, see e.g. WindowBlinds). But your best bet is to disable themes for the control and do the rendering yourself using custom draw.

Comment: Just an idea: use a memory DC (DIB section) as the target for `DrawThemeBackgroundEx`, colorize the pixels as you like and `BitBlt` the result to the screen. Colorization could be as simple as multiplying the luminance value of each pixel by your preferred color.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning custom draw i think this will achieve what i want! When you add some sample code i can accept it as an answer.